# Can list.get(list.size() - 1) be shortened? e.g. list.get(-1)

Tags: java, list

Is there a 'short way' in Java, to ***access*** the *last* element in an *ArrayList* (or *Array*)?

'short way'  =  Without ***repeating*** the var name (once before the get, and once in the get) .

My motivation is easiness of reading/writing/maintaining.

e.g. Access the last Page of the last Book:

C++ :

```
LastPageOfLastBook  = MyLibraryVar.Books.back().Pages.back();
```

C# 8.0:

```
LastPageOfLastBook  = MyLibraryVar.Books[^1].Pages[^1];
```

Java :

```
LastPageOfLastBook  = MyLibraryVar.Books.get(MyLibraryVar.Books.size()-1)
 .Pages.get(MyLibraryVar.Books.get(MyLibraryVar.Books.size()-1).Pages.size()-1);
```

That is a lot shorter and easy to maintain/read/write.
Note, that var names could be longer, so it could be more significant.  Also what if one wants to access the last word in the last line, in the last page in the last book ...   (i.e. 4 dimensions, instead of just 2.)

( C#'s *Array*, behaves for that matter as *ArrayList*, guess the same is correct also for Java)

###########
Other info that is *not* directly related to the question :

Regarding *removal* of the last element into my own var. I found no out-of-the-bax solution in neither C++,c# nor Java. ( Jave afaik scores the best at that, as it's 'remove-by-index' at least returns the element removed).

C++ has `std::vector::pop_back()` to remove-last , `std::vector::back()` to access-last last element  ( thanks @sweenish).
C# has `List[^1]` to access-last, and `List.RemoveAt(^1)` to remove-last.  But c#/c++ remove does *not* return the item, in that regard, i prefer the Java way over c++/c#  )

Comment: You are not looking for well-performing solution but you simply want to type the least amount of characters, why!? Because what other disadvantages does `size()` have?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Using size is by far the best solution. You could use `list.stream().reduce(o1, o2 -> o2)` to get the last element, but it's very expensive compared to the standard solution.

Comment: I think this question is just about being curious whether you can make it more compact, for "lazyness". Which is fair, after all, most languages have `.get(-1)` or `getLast()` or a reverse iterator or similar.

Comment: `LinkedList` has methods [`addLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast--), [`getLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#getLast--) [`removeLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLast--) defined in interface [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)

Comment: @magicmn "You could use" no, don't even mention that as an option. That's a terrible way to do it.

Comment: If `get(size() - 1)` really offends you, you can write a helper method which gets the last item. Such methods already exist e.g. [in Guava Iterables](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#getLast-java.lang.Iterable-T-); but all these do internally (for `List` anyway) is to use `get(size() - 1)`.

Comment: @user207421 So, like, I mean, that's why I left a comment. The question also specifically calls out C++. My comment just fills in the knowledge gap left there by the text in the question. That seems relevant enough for a **comment**.

Comment: @luk2302 you have a point. question was unclear, added a code example. hope my intention is clearer. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

> 'short way' = Without calling 'size()', nor repeating the the var name.

No. Just get used to

```java
E last = list.get(list.size() - 1);
// and
list.remove(list.size() - 1);
```

Java has no short-hand like `list.get(-1)` or `list.getLast()` or similar for `List`s, unlike some other languages.

---

### Iterator

Something that, depending on what you are planning to do, might also be interesting is the [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()):

```java
ListIterator<E> iter = list.listIterator(list.size() - 1);
```

This gives you an iterator to the back and you can now traverse the list in both directions and remove or add elements via the `iter` directly. For `LinkedList` those operations would then also be in `O(1)`.

This is more similar to the C++ interface which is all about such *"iterator objects"*.

---

### Deque

Note that there is also the interface [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) which is all about providing direct access to the **head** and **tail**. Hence, it provides methods like

- `getLast()`, `peekLast()`
- `removeLast()`, `pollLast()`
- `addLast(e)`, `offerLast(e)`

Commonly used implementations are `ArrayDeque` (not `ArrayList`) but also `LinkedList`, which happens to also be a `List`.

Comment: "Java has no short-hand like" it is ambiguous to allow -1 to mean "last element": did you mean to ask for the last element of the list, or did you just mess up your arithmetic?

Comment: @AndyTurner I am just referring to OPs question who asked whether java has `list.get(-1)` or similar to get the last element. Some languages do allow negative indices to start the lookup from the back, so `list.get(-1)` (in other languages) gives the last element. For example `list[-1]` in Python, `list[^1]` in C# and so on.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate that: I'm pointing out a reason why it's not necessarily a desirable behavior.

Comment: I see, thats fair, good point.

Comment: @Zabuzard  @AndyTurner  :   see  edits to question. It does not have to be -1 , ^1 . C++ used `back()` others  `top` . Other make `it`  refer to collection inside the `get`,  so it looks like  `list.get(  it.size() -1 )` .    other langs use "$" to refer to last element in that context.     Note,  many times a big code base already exists, and it is not trivial to tell if one can change ArrayLIst to LinkedList, as code may already contain calls to 'get'  in many places.  ( not sure what is gained by that, anyway)

Comment: @rankeren your question asks if you can in Java, not if it's possible to design a language and/or API to do so. You can't use these in Java.

Comment: @rankeren Regardless of how many examples you find in other languages, Java does not have something like that. What I showed in my answer is all that is available that somehow goes into that direction.